# rendering apex:tab based on 'multi select' picklist

Tags: visualforce

I need to render visualforce tabs in a tabpanel based on whether a multiselect picklist field is selected. But not getting the tab to show/hide using the following (*Revised*) approach:

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="true" standardController="Account_Summary__c" readOnly="false"  showHeader="true"  >
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.pdfcssresource, 'CREresource_CRE.css')}"/>
<apex:form id="form1">
<apex:pageBlock id="block1"  >
<apex:actionRegion > 

<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="section1" title="General Information" showHeader="true" >

    <apex:inputField value="{!Account_Summary__c.Lines_of_Business__c}" style="color:blue;" >
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="tab1a,tab1b,tab1c,theTabPanel" /> 
        </apex:inputField>          
    <apex:inputField value="{!Account_Summary__c.Other_Line_of_Business__c}"  style="color:blue;" rendered="{!CONTAINS(Account_Summary__c.Lines_of_Business__c,'Other')}" />'

</apex:pageBlockSection>

<apex:actionRegion immediate="true" >    
<apex:outputPanel >
<b><apex:outputText style="font-style:bold;color:blue" value="Line of Business Analysis" /></b>

<apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="name2" id="theTabPanel">
<apex:tab label="TEST1" name="tab1a" id="tab1a" rendered="{!CONTAINS(Account_Summary__c.Lines_of_Business__c,'Workers Compensation')}" > </apex:tab>
<apex:tab label="TEST2" name="tab1b" id="tab1b" rendered="{INCLUDES(Account_Summary__c.Lines_of_Business__c,'Workers Compensation')}" > </apex:tab>
<apex:tab label="TEST3" name="tab1c" id="tab1c" rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(Account_Summary__c.Lines_of_Business__c,'Workers Compensation'),"true","false")}"  > </apex:tab>

</apex:tabPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:actionRegion>


</apex:actionRegion>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: It should be `INCLUDES`, not `CONTAINS`.

Comment: Function INCLUDES may not be used in this type of formula

Comment: !INCLUDES results in error. INCLUDES does not fix rendering issue. Have used!CONTAINS with other multi-select fields rendering . For some reason not on this one.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a CASE formula [function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm). Please find the below example where `Country__c` is a picklist which contains different Country names.

```
<!-- Page: -->
<apex:page standardController="Book__c" id="thePage">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Book__c.Country__c}">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="theTabPanel" />
        </apex:inputField>
    </apex:form>
    <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="name2" id="theTabPanel">
        <apex:tab label="One" name="name1" id="tabOne" rendered="{!CASE(Book__c.Country__c,"USA", "true","false")}">content for tab one</apex:tab>
        <apex:tab label="Two" name="name2" id="tabTwo">content for tab two</apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>
</apex:page>
```

In your code the rendered attribute should be changed to this.

```
rendered="{!CASE(Account_Summary__c.Lines_of_Business__c,"Workers Compensation", "true","false")}"
```

If you using multi-select picklist you can use the `CONTAINS` function. In the below example `multipicklist__c` is a multi-select picklist which contains A,B,C,D E.

```
<!-- Page: -->
<apex:page standardController="Book__c" id="thePage">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Book__c.multipicklist__c}">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="theTabPanel" />
        </apex:inputField>        
    </apex:form>
    <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="name2" id="theTabPanel">
        <apex:tab label="One" name="name1" id="tabOne">content for tab one</apex:tab>
        <apex:tab label="Two" name="name2" id="tabTwo" rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(Book__c.multipicklist__c,"A") && CONTAINS(Book__c.multipicklist__c,"B"),"true","false")}" >content for tab two</apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>
</apex:page>
```

> Update code according to updated question.

```
<!-- Page: -->
<apex:page standardController="Book__c" id="thePage">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock id="block1"  >
            <apex:actionRegion >
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="section1" title="General Information" showHeader="true" >
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Book__c.multipicklist__c}">
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="outputpanel" />
                    </apex:inputField> 
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:actionRegion immediate="true" >
                    <apex:outputPanel id="outputpanel"  >
                        <apex:tabPanel  switchType="client" selectedTab="name2" rendered="{!CASE(Book__c.multipicklist__c,'A', 'true','false')}"  id="theTabPanel">
                            <apex:tab label="One" name="name1" id="tabOne">content for tab one</apex:tab>
                            <apex:tab label="Two" name="name2" id="tabTwo">content for tab two</apex:tab> 
                        </apex:tabPanel>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:actionRegion>
            </apex:actionRegion>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Still not working. Added revised code above in original post.

Comment: The above example is a working example. Can you please post your entire page structure containing all major elements, like `<apex:page .. <apex:form ... <apex:actionRegion .. <apex:inputfield ... <apex:actionsupport`. You  may show only these major dependent elements skipping rest of the code.

Comment: I added a short version of the complete page. Still, rendering is not working. The tab 'TEST1' shows with nothing in the pick. Choose any value and tab TEST1 dissapears. TEST2 and TEST3 tabs never show.

Comment: What is `Lines_of_Business__c` field, is it _multi select_ or _single select_? I tried your code structure and it is working for me. Can you please explain a little bit more on the conditions for tab hide and show.

Comment: Multi select pick list .  Do all three test tabs render or just one of them.

Comment: In that Case you should only re-render only the `<apex:outputPanel >` and put the rendered for only  for `<apex:tabPanel` element. Check my updated, I have used same structure as yours.

Comment: There are some rich text fields in the various tabs. So when I rerender the <apex:tabPanel> element and error is thrown as 'Rerender is not currently supported with rich text editing enabled.'  There are a good amount of rich text fields in the tabs. Any best idea how to get around that ?

Comment: Also, I need to render each tab. In your example, rendering would show tab "One" and "Two." In my case if "Workers Compensation" is contained in the picklist selection then I would want to just show the tab for Workers Compensation (tab "One" for example.)